# Convert CString array to System::String

Tags: c#, c++, mfc, cstring

I want to convert CString array to managed code ot send it to C#.
For normal CString i did like this,

```
CString menu = "MENU";
String ^ msg = gcnew String(menu);
Globals1::gwtoolbar->Add(msg);
```

But now i want to send array of string.i dont know how to do for CString array.

When i gave like this it shows error

```
CString menu[10];
String[] ^ msg = gcnew String(menu);
```

How can i convert it?

Comment: this looks more like c++ than c#, no?

Comment: Might me.Im doing this coding in VC++ only.Im sending data from VC++ to C# dll using in VC++ application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given:

```
CString menu[10]
```

To convert to a managed array of String:

```
#DEFINE MENU_COUNT 10;

array<String^>^ clrMenu = gcnew array<String^>(MENU_COUNT);

for (int i = 0; i < MENU_COUNT; ++i)
{
    clrMenu[i] = gcnew String(menu[i]);
}
```